# Creating two equal width input with col-md-6 inside a Tab leaves spaces in between

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create two input which would take equal space inside a Tab. Code as below.

```
<tabset justified="true">
                <tab heading="TAB1">
                    <h1>TAB1</h1>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Loading station">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Unloading station">
                    </div>
</tab>
</tabset>
```

There is some space in between the inputs which I dont want. Please help to fix this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, the '.col-lg-6' class (or any similar class) have padding applied on them; You don't give too much detail in your description (Will the site be responsive? etc) so the immediate solution to your problem should be:

```
.col-lg-6 {
  padding:0;
}
```